# open three different activity after login with three different users in android studio

Tags: java, android

If I login with on user type then it should open that user type activity and if others then it should open other user type activity. That means I wanted to open three different activity when I authenticate with specific user type.

Attached database image:

[image]

```
package com.example.studentcoordinator;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.LoginFilter;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Login_Form extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtEmail, txtPassword;
    Button btn_login;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login__form);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login Page");

        txtEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signinemail);
        txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signinpassword);
        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);


        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = txtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = txtPassword.getText().toString().trim();


                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {

                    Toast.makeText(Login_Form.this, "Please Enter Valid Email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

                    Toast.makeText(Login_Form.this, "Please Enter Valid Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (password.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(Login_Form.this, "Password Too Short", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                displayloader();


                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(Login_Form.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Form.this, Coordinator_homepage.class);
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    startActivity(intent);

                                } else {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Failed Or User Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });

            }
        });


    }

    public void displayloader() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_Form.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Logging .. Please Wait !!");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: In this I tried with Firebase authentication method but i want it using realtime database

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use switch case for that

```
switch (role) {
        case "Teacher":
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this , TeacherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case "Student":
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this , StudentActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case "Coordinator":
            Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this , CoordinatorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
```

Comment: But how it understand whether its Teacher case or student case. I mean where i will mention this. Please explain in details as I am new in Android.

Comment: @HarshalGadakh define role in your user model like name and email server should tell you this user's role. what is in your AuthResult model ?

Comment: I need to open three different activities for updating and checking data as per their role. So Please tell me how I will read data from real time DB and then how to use above condition.